# Cannot convert from 'void' to System.Threading.Tasks.Task<System.Action>

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, hangfire

I have write generic method using hangfire .Net. Basically i want to achieve that i have generate one method and want to call it multiple times when ever it is required. My helper method is below:

```
 public static void ScheduleBackGroundJob(Task<Action> _refmethod, DateTime _dateTime)
    {
        try
        {
            var _currentDate = DateTime.Now;
            TimeSpan _timeSpan = _dateTime - _currentDate;
            BackgroundJob.Schedule(() => _refmethod, _timeSpan);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

I want to call this method using like this

```
HangfireHelper.ScheduleBackGroundJob(_service.UpdateAuctionStatus(result), result.PlannedCloseDate);
```

My updateAuctionStatus Method is below.

```
public void UpdateAuctionStatus(AuctionReturnModel model)
    {
        try
        {
            var _auction = (from d in _db.Auction_Detail where d.Id == model.AuctionDetailId select d).FirstOrDefault();
            _auction.isEnded = true;
            _db.Auction_Detail.Add(_auction);
            _db.SaveChanges();

            var _auctionHistory = new AuctionHistory { AuctionDetail_Id = model.AuctionDetailId, EndedDate = DateTime.Now, EndedMethod = "Automatic" };
            _db.AuctionHistory.Add(_auctionHistory);
            _db.SaveChanges();

            Task.WaitAll();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
           throw ex;
        }
    }
```

My getting the above error cannot convert into void. I want to call it by sending any method as a parameter.

Comment: Task.WaitAll(); --> this does nothing in this context. not sure if it may cause your error

Comment: You're not passing a method, you're trying to *call* `_service.UpdateAuctionStatus(result)` and pass its *return value*  (i.e. `void`) to a parameter expecting `Task<Action>`, hence the error. Your parameter should perhaps just be an `Action`, instead of `Task<Action>`, and then you can pass `() => _service.UpdateAuctionStatus(result)` instead.

Comment: when i convert it Task<Action> to Action it gives me the error call background.schedule job and passing the action parameter as i am doing.

Comment: Basically what i want to achieve is to reuse HangfireHelper.ScheduleBackGroundJob()  method. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done it by changing my methods like

```
 public static void ScheduleBackGroundJob(Expression<Action> _refmethod, DateTime _dateTime)
    {
        try
        {
            var _currentDate = DateTime.Now;
            TimeSpan _timeSpan = _dateTime - _currentDate;
            BackgroundJob.Schedule(_refmethod, _timeSpan);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

Calling Hangfire helper code

```
 HangfireHelper.ScheduleBackGroundJob(() => _service.UpdateAuctionStatus(result), result.PlannedCloseDate);
```

My service method i have change this

```
  public async Task UpdateAuctionStatus(AuctionReturnModel model)
    {
        try
        {
            var _auction = await (from d in _db.Auction_Detail where d.Id == model.AuctionDetailId select d).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
            _auction.isEnded = true;
            _db.Auction_Detail.Add(_auction);
            _db.SaveChanges();

            var _auctionHistory = new AuctionHistory { AuctionDetail_Id = model.AuctionDetailId, EndedDate = DateTime.Now, EndedMethod = "Automatic" };
            _db.AuctionHistory.Add(_auctionHistory);
            _db.SaveChanges();

            Task.WaitAll();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

Hope this will help you in future. Any code reviews and best practices will be highly appreciated because i am always looking to learn something new and better approaches to solve problems.